# Auto Place Text Frames Below Each Other (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, adobe-indesign

I am trying to automate inDesign to create text frames from a JSON file, where every record shall be placed in a text frame, which is right below the foregoing record.

```
var tweets_json = '[ {"name":"record_1"}, {"name":"record_2"}, ... ]';  // I have not yet figured out how to import external JSON files, so tor testing this is my current way to go
var tweets = eval("(" + tweets_json + ")");

for ( var t = 0; t < tweets.length; t++ ) {
  var newTextFrame = page.textFrames.add();
  newTextFrame.textFramePreferences.autoSizingType = AutoSizingTypeEnum.HEIGHT_ONLY;
  var tweet = tweets[ t ];

  newTextFrame.parentStory.texts.item(0).applyParagraphStyle(styleContent, true);
  newTextFrame.geometricBounds = [y1,x1,y2,x2];   // Ignore values
  newTextFrame.contents = tweet.name;
}
```

I started inDesign scripting a few days ago and the documentation is hard to find the solution i am looking for, especially with my basic JavaScript knowledge, so any help is appreciated! Thank You!

Comment: You can read basic JSON files this way: `var json = $.evalFile(File('d:\\temp\\my_file.json'));`. As for the rest, the code looks quite well. All you need is to adjust the `y1,x1,y2,x2` coordinates for every next text frame. Do you need help with it?

Comment: Hey Yuri, your solution for evaluating the json worked perfectly! As for the coordinates I have the problem that the heights vary from each text frame and `newTextFrame.geometricBounds` contains the values of the current text frame. What I need is instead a variable which contains the y2-coordinate from the previous text frame. Do you have any recommendation how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be something like this:

```
var doc = app.activeDocument;
var page = doc.pages[0];

// get JSON data (just as an example)
var tweets_json = '[ {"name":"line1 line2"}, {"name":"line3"}, {"name":"line4, line5"}]';
var tweets = eval("(" + tweets_json + ")");

// set geometric bounds for the first text frame
var x = 0, y = 0;                          // coordinates of top a left corner of the text frame
var width = 15;                            // width of the text frame
var min_heigth = 20;                       // minimal heigth of the text frame
var bottom = min_heigth;                   // bottom edge of the text frame
var bounds = [y, x, bottom, width];

for (var t = 0; t < tweets.length; t++) {
    var tweet = tweets[t];

    // create the a new text frame and set its geometric bounds
    var newTextFrame = page.textFrames.add();
    newTextFrame.geometricBounds = bounds;

    // fill the box with a text and apply the style
    newTextFrame.contents = tweet.name;
    newTextFrame.parentStory.texts[0].applyParagraphStyle(styleContent, true);

    // resize the created text box with auto sizing
    newTextFrame.textFramePreferences.autoSizingReferencePoint = AutoSizingReferenceEnum.TOP_CENTER_POINT;
    newTextFrame.textFramePreferences.autoSizingType = AutoSizingTypeEnum.HEIGHT_ONLY;

    // set the new geometric bounds for the next text frame
    bounds = newTextFrame.geometricBounds; // get the bounds of the created text frame
    bottom = bounds[2];                    // get the new bottom edge
    bounds[0] = bottom;                    // set the top edge for the next text frame
    bounds[2] = bounds[2] + min_heigth;    // set the bottom edge for the next text frame
}
```

Result:

[image]

The code a bit verbose, for educational purposes. Actually it can be way shorter.

Comment: Thank you, Yuri! This was exactly what I was looking for. This absolutely makes sense, never thought about setting the start coordinates outside the `for`loop. Thank you very much.